# Why casting a sphere to a cube give cylinder+cube?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to cast a sphere to a cube, but when I add the modifier, it seems like a cilinder inside a cube.... why?

[image]

My Cast modifier settings are: Factor=1, Radius=0, Size=0 , as I saw on a guide (I want to keep the same dimensions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

The image above shows a blue mesh with a sphere shape, hereafter the blue sphere.  It is symmetric about the 3 axis similar to a cube.  Note the red faces have a 3 face corner not a 4 face corner. Not a UV Sphere.  The mesh will work symmetrically along x, y, z axis with a cast cuboid modifier.

In the image in your original question concentric rings of the UV Sphere are placed along the z-axis.  Speaking about the default situation.  So the there is an asymmetry regarding the z-axis.  So the [cast] modifier mathematics amplifies this asymmetry.  You will get slightly better results if you subdivide your mesh again.

You can edit the blue sphere in [edit] mode and rotate 90 on the y axis.  The asymmetry deformation will be rotated as well.

Here is the same blue sphere shaped mesh with a cast modifier.  Note again the red faces which form a 3 face corner of a cube.

[image]

To create a NON-UV sphere shaped mesh.  Create a cube. In [edit] mode loop cut on with 7 or so divisions. Loop Cut on all three axis XYZ.  Menu Transform ..... Transform to Sphere.

Yes, start with cube, transform to sphere shape, cast back to cuboid.

Additional Notes
Please welcome Carlo

---

**Cast modifier** basically projects the object vertices along their normals to the target shape's surface. It is the same thing you would get by using a Shrinkwrap modifier pointing to a scene object.

[image]
[image]

By enabling Vertex normals in Edit mode, you can see on what surface each vertex will be translated to.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

There is no vertex pointing toward the box's corner.

[image]

**Conclusions:**
To better approximate a cube, the starting sphere should have enough vertex density whose vertex normals point to the cube edges and corners. So for better results you can:

- Increase the number of vertices
- Use a different starting topology

Comment: @Carlo  Yes.  You have been reserved a space [after] what I have already written.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my "unmissable" stuff. Feel free to change or rearrange things in order to provide a higher coherence level to the answer.

Comment: @Carlo  please change the word you wrote ..... [project] to [projects]