# Transforming a cube to a sphere using transform to sphere isn't creating a sphere it creates a spike shaped mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]
Took a screenshot of blender pressed f6 to show the options that were by default for the to sphere transform. It creates a spiked shape mesh not sure why any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38019/why-casting-a-sphere-to-a-cube-give-cylindercube/38021#38021

Comment: You are showing an image. That is good. I suggest you show before and after images for more clarity. There is a proposed answer below.  If you are a beginner you may have made a mistake which maybe easier to delete than to correct.  There is the Undo feature in Blender.  A fresh start sometimes is easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a scaling issue here. If you take a cube and:

1. In edit mode, subdivide it
2. In object mode, scale it along one axis
3. Back in edit mode scale it back down the axis so it looks like a cube again
4. And then use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> .. 'To Sphere'

...you wind up with a similar result to yours.

In short, in object mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> apply any scale that might be locked into the object's transform matrix.

If *ever* you make a non-uniform scale of something in Object Mode.. make a mental note of it, and/or keep an eye on the Transform panel in the Properties Region of the 3D view (in Object Mode). You may need to go back and bake the transform into the mesh by applying it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a sphere shape

[image]

- Start with the cube.  Ooops. Barely visible under menu.
- Edit Mode subdivide some reasonable number, perhaps 3 or 5, for vertex density and cpu efficiency
- Edit Mode To Sphere (Not Modifier). Menu Selection and Keystroke is in the image above.
- Consider Shape Keys
- There are always may ways to produce similar creations in Blender

[image]

Image above shows the high density cube transformed to sphere shape.  Well maybe not so high density.
You might start with sphere and then use shape keys to add spikes.